# Error on ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: asp.net, t-sql, c#-4.0, ado.net

I get the following error from `ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
"String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated."
```

The problem is the variable to be sent is bigger that the one in the DB.
I am using the following code:

```
      protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        var Username = (Label)row.FindControl("Label3");
        var Password = (Label)row.FindControl("Label4");
        var Email = (Label)row.FindControl("Label5");
       // var ID_Inscricao = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;
        var ID_Inscricao = ((Label)row.FindControl("Label1")).Text;


        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FormacaoConnectionString"].ToString());
        SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand();


        sqlComm = sqlConn.CreateCommand();
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.Text);
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.Text);
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.Text);
        sqlComm.Parameters.Add("@ID_Inscricao", SqlDbType.Int);

        sqlComm.Parameters["@Username"].Value = Convert.ToString(Username);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@Password"].Value = Convert.ToString(Password);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@Email"].Value = Convert.ToString(Email);
        sqlComm.Parameters["@ID_Inscricao"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ID_Inscricao);

        string sql = "INSERT INTO Utilizadores (Username, Password, Email, ID_Inscricao) VALUES (@Username, @Password, @Email, @ID_Inscricao)";
        sqlComm.CommandText = sql;
        sqlConn.Open();
        sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens when you try to insert something into a column that is too long for that column.

For example, when you have a column `VARCHAR(10)` and you try to insert the value `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"`. This would lead to the data being truncated and that generates an error.

I can't tell which column it is in your case but it has to be one of `Username`, `Password` or `Email`.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to truncate the value you're inserting.

Comment: I suppose 33 is a value for your `ID_Inscricao` column? The problem is not in that column.

Comment: going to modify db to alow 100 char

Comment: so it seems that it worked. But im getting the values from the gridview with a full field, like i have the Data inside plus the size of the field in spaces.

Comment: its the a easy way of cleaning the many extra space that come from getting the value.

Comment: @user1587816 If you use char then the data includes spaces at the end to the size of the char.  If you use varchar then you will get back only the data.  In asp.net you could trim the end.   I typically use varchar just so I don't have to trim.

Comment: At the same place you use `CHAR` right now. `VARCHAR` is a data type just like `CHAR`, `INT`, `BIGINT`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the data type in the database you are trying to populate is smaller than one of the values you are passing.  You need to check each of your parameters @Username, @Password and @Email and see which one is larger than the database data type.  Then you can increase the size of the data type in the database if required, or trim the parameter values before sending.

Comment: true i already modified the types so its "equal" to the database, but still same error.

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dim qry As String
        qry = "inserg into Table1 values('" & TextBox1.Text & "'+'" & TextBox2.Text & "'+'" & DropDownList1.Text & "'+'" & DropDownList2.Text & "'+'" & TextBox4.Text & "'+'" & TextBox5.Text & "'+'" & RadioButtonList1.Text & "'+'" & RadioButton1.Text & "'+'" & RadioButtonList2.Text & "'+'" & CheckBoxList1.Text & "'+'" & TextBox6.Text & "'+'" & TextBox7.Text & "'+'" & TextBox8.Text & "'+'" & TextBox9.Text & "'+'" & TextBox10.Text & "'+'" & RadioButtonList3.Text & "'"
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\MCALab\My Documents\net.mdb")
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(qry, cn)
        cn.Open()
        **cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()**this line have error please any one know mean debug it.

        cn.Close()
```